# Remap Tmux prefix to control + control

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

Is it possible to use the same key twice in `tmux` for the prefix character? I. e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd>?